# Vim mapping of <Bar>, \|, ^V(c-v c-v), and <NL>(c-v c-j)

Tags: vim

Trying to `:read!` the `:set runtimepath?` command.

`:set runtimepath` and `:set runtimepath?` work; the paths shows in the buffer.

This gives the key-mappings:

`:help {key}^D`.

Nothing out of the ordinary was seen; checked `^V(c-v c-v)`, `\|`, `^@(c-v c-j`, `<bar>`, etc.

I have cycled through, in the following order:

```
:read! \| set -runtimepath?
:read! <Bar> set -runtimepath?
:read! ^V set -runtimepath?
:read! set -runtimepath ^V ?
:read! ^@ set -runtimepath? <--this showed the paths in buffer, but did not read
:0,i read! +(set runtimepath ^V?) error, trailing chars
```

This is a portion of my attempt; here are a few more of my errors, such as

```
/tmp/vaRUOTA/2 2>&1
/tmp/vaRUOTA/0 cant read
e485: cant read file /tmp/vaRUOTA/4
```

I ran this with sudo.

I have some basic questions: such as where does vim `:set` (it is not the anon reg)?, is `?` a parameter/cmd to be piped/ bkwd lookup.?

thank you in advance for any help

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: these are vi commands. :read reads a file; :read! reads a cmd output to the cursor; so that's what i am trying to do. the :set returns all the paths; id like those in the lines below my cursor.

Comment: I know what those commands are. What is not clear at all from your question is what you actually want to do with them. So now it sems you want to insert the value of `runtimepath` in your

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert the value of `&runtimepath` under the current line with this command:

```
:put=&runtimepath
```

If you want the output of `:set runtimepath`, you will need to use the `:redir` command:

```
:redir @"
:set runtimepath
:redir END
p
```

Note that the value of `&runtimepath` and the output of `:set runtimepath` are different:

```
:echo &runtimepath
/home/user/.vim,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles…

:set runtimepath
runtimepath=~/.vim,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles…
```

One uses absolute paths and the other a mix of absolute and relative paths.

Why you would want to insert that info in a buffer is not very clear to me, though. What is your ultimate goal, exactly?

Comment: no real reason, just curious. I was configuring a plugin (fugitive) for vim last night.  That was straightforward enough, so I though Id play with this... thanks